# Using the `survey` package in R to estimate covariances between overlapping domains

Tags: r, survey

## Question:

Suppose we have survey data measuring vaccination status for two overlapping domains, persons aged 30-50 and persons aged 40-60, and we want to estimate vaccination rates for these two groups. Clearly the domain estimates will be correlated because of the overlap (persons aged 40-50).

**How can we use the `survey` package to estimate the covariance of estimates from overlapping domains such as these?**

Ideally, is it possible to use `svyby()` or `svybys()` to do this?

### Example Data:

Below is an example based on the `api` dataset built into the `survey` package. This is a multistage sample of schools in California. The variable `stype` indicates whether a school is an elementary, middle, or high school. The variable `api00` is a numeric variable which summarizes each school's performance on standardized tests in the year 2000.

For this example, let's suppose we want to compare the average of `api00` between two overlapping domains: (1) elementary and middle schools; and (2) middle and high schools.

```r
# Create a survey design object ----
  library(survey)
  data(api)
  
  dclus2 <- svydesign(id=~dnum+snum,
                      fpc=~fpc1+fpc2,
                      data=apiclus2)
  
# Add indicator variables for the domains ----

  dclus2 <- transform(dclus2,
                      E_or_M = stype %in% c("E", "M"),
                      M_or_H = stype %in% c("M", "H"))
  
# Add variables for outcome by domain indicators ----
  
  dclus2 <- transform(dclus2,
                      api00_E_or_M = api00 * E_or_M,
                      api00_M_or_H = api00 * M_or_H)

# Estimate means by domain ----
  
  estimates <- list(
    'E_or_M' = svyratio(~ api00_E_or_M, ~ E_or_M,
                        design = dclus2),
    'M_or_H' = svyratio(~ api00_M_or_H, ~ M_or_H,
                        design = dclus2)
  )

  sapply(estimates, function(est) est[['ratio']])
#>  E_or_M   M_or_H 
#> 682.0563 623.8102
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `svyratio()` function with the option `covmat = TRUE` to get these estimates and their variance-covariance matrix.

```r
  estimates <- svyratio(numerator = ~ api00_E_or_M + api00_M_or_H,
                        denominator = ~ E_or_M + M_or_H,
                        design = dclus2, covmat = TRUE)
```

The only challenge is that the output contains the estimates you care about in addition to estimates you don't care about. In the output below, we only care about the diagonal elements.

```r
> estimates$ratio
#>               E_or_M    M_or_H
#> api00_E_or_M 682.0563 1851.9722
#> api00_M_or_H 229.7408  623.8102

estimates_of_interest <- diag(estimates$ratio)
print(estimates_of_interest)
#> [1] 682.0563 623.8102
```

Similarly, the variance-covariance matrix you get from calling `vcov()` contains estimated variances and covariances for ratios we don't care about, as you can see below.

```r
  full_vcov <- vcov(estimates)
  
  print(full_vcov)
#>                     api00_E_or_M/E_or_M api00_M_or_H/E_or_M api00_E_or_M/M_or_H
#> api00_E_or_M/E_or_M          1047.29150            34.07083            5189.788
#> api00_M_or_H/E_or_M            34.07083          2743.16185          -22346.457
#> api00_E_or_M/M_or_H          5189.78822        -22346.45657          211988.476
#> api00_M_or_H/M_or_H           882.76208          -109.79708            5981.838
#>                     api00_M_or_H/M_or_H
#> api00_E_or_M/E_or_M            882.7621
#> api00_M_or_H/E_or_M           -109.7971
#> api00_E_or_M/M_or_H           5981.8380
#> api00_M_or_H/M_or_H            909.3903
```

So to get the variance-covariance matrix we actually care about, we have to subset it like so:

```r
  vcov_of_estimates <- full_vcov[c("api00_E_or_M/E_or_M", "api00_M_or_H/M_or_H"),
                                 c("api00_E_or_M/E_or_M", "api00_M_or_H/M_or_H")]
  
  print(vcov_of_estimates)
#>                     api00_E_or_M/E_or_M api00_M_or_H/M_or_H
#> api00_E_or_M/E_or_M           1047.2915            882.7621
#> api00_M_or_H/M_or_H            882.7621            909.3903
```

The statistical details are explained in this blog post:
https://www.practicalsignificance.com/posts/how-correlated-are-survey-estimates-from-overlapping-groups/